# How do I schedule tasks on termux using at-command?

Tags: unix, termux

There is no problem with installing [**at**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(command)) on **termux**. But if I try to setup a job, I get an error

`"Can't open /var/run/atd.pid to signal atd. No atd running?"`

and the job do not execute on the given shedule.

Somebody an idea how to fix this?

Comment: What environment is this? Have you checked what the message says, that atd should be running?

Comment: @vonbrand environment is an android smartphone. 
How can I check if the *atd* is running?

Comment: I'm surprised it isn't running, normally this should have been started at startup. You might check if it's working using `ps -ef` but I'll advise you to check your `/etc/init.d`: did it crash or hasn't it been started up?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to start this daemon:

```
atd start
```

(Your `PATH` environment should be set up in such a way that the `atd` daemon is found)

Furthermore, as mentioned in my comment, I advise you to check your `/etc/init.d`.